# implement the bit map in the following situation

Tags: c, bitmap

My question is how to implement the bit map in the following situation?
If a vertex of a graph is in a minimum spanning tree (MST), mark the corresponding bit; later on check whether it is in the MST by checking the bit.

At beginning, I was thinking of using

```
typedef struct bit_t{    
   char bit0:1;
} bit;       

bit bitmap[num_of_vertex];
```

And use bitmap array to record the bit;

But then I found the sizeof (bitmap[num_of_vertex]) is num_of_vertex byte, not num_of_vertex/8 byte. so it is not saving space like what I thought;

So far I use

```
long bit_record = 0;   
...
bit_record |= 1<< u;//set vertex as in MST    
...
```

then later on check whether vertex is in MST using:

```
static bool is_in_MST(int v, int bit_record){   
    int mask = 1 <<  v;   
    if (mask & bit_record)    
        return true;   
    else    
        return false;   
}
```

Though the code works, it will not work if num_of_vertex is larger than 32.

How in general a bitmap in the above situation is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about bitmap,here is an example on Programming Pearls, and I added up some notes:

```
#define BITPERWORD  32 //bits of int，which depends on your computer
#define N           10000000 // number of your elements
#define SHIFT       5 // 32 = 2^5
#define MASK        0x1F // 11111 in binary 
int a[N/BITPERWORD + 1]; //space for your bitmap

// i is the the bit you want to use
void set(int i)     {        a[i>>SHIFT] |=  (1<<(i&MASK));}
void clr(int i)     {        a[i>>SHIFT] &= ~(1<<(i&MASK));}
int  test(int i)    { return a[i>>SHIFT] &   (1<<(i&MASK));}
```

and don't forget the initialization at the beginning:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    clr(i);
```

Comment: Init can be done faster by iterating over the array and just set that to 0, ie `for (i=0; i< N/BITPERWORD+1;i++) a[i] = 0;`

Comment: @flolo but it calculate `N/BITPERWORD+1` everytime. I think you mean that `int temp = N/BITPERWORD+1; for (i=0; i< temp;i++) a[i] = 0;`

Comment: every optimizing compiler, that deserves this name would recognize it as loop invariant code and would not recompute it every iteration.

Comment: it is a little hard for me to understand this code at beginning. So let me explain this approach to myself: i>>SHIFT is the same as i/INT_BIT; i&MASK is the same as i%INT_BIT. e.g. 3&MASK we get 3, 35&MASK we still get 3. We use 0x in MASK because MASK is a base 16 number. In summary this approach is the same as H2CO3's approach using division and modulus.

Answer (score 5):

The situation is that you just **can't have 1-bit types in C.** The smallest addressable unit is a byte in C, so even if you declare a struct with a one-bit bitfield, it will be padded to a byte (at least). What you can do is create an array of bytes, then access the bits in the array using division and modulus.

```
unsigned char bitmap[0x100] = { 0 };

void set_nth_bit(unsigned char *bitmap, int idx)
{
    bitmap[idx / CHAR_BIT] |= 1 << (idx % CHAR_BIT);
}

void clear_nth_bit(unsigned char *bitmap, int idx)
{
    bitmap[idx / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1 << (idx % CHAR_BIT));
}

int get_nth_bit(unsigned char *bitmap, int idx)
{
    return (bitmap[idx / CHAR_BIT] >> (idx % CHAR_BIT)) & 1;
}
```

Comment: interesting and workable! is it a regular way for bitmap implementation?

Comment: @user389955 What do you mean by "regular"? Of course I didn't just throw together random symbols...

Comment: I mean a general, commonly used solution

Comment: @user389955 Yes, it definitely is.